# Will react setState immedietly set the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to store a value using setState, however I am setting the state and in next line I am trying to console.log it, I am not able to see the value in the console.

```js
getInitialState: function(){
    return{
        myCountry: ""
      }
  }


var country = event.target.value;
this.setState({"myCountry": country});
console.log(this.state.myCountry); //prints nothing
console.log(event.target.value);
```

When I surfed for this I saw that setState is asynchronous, but I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not get the updated value of state just after calling setState(). This is because as soon as setState() is called view is re-rendered. So it is better to check the updated value inside render or add callback function to setState.
**Example:**

```
this.setState({"myCountry": country},function(){console.log(this.state.myCountry)});
```

Or,

```
render: function() {
    console.log(this.state.myCountry)
}
```

Comment: This is only correct depending on what part of the component lifecycle is currently active. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

NO

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

IF you want to check the updated state you can try logging it in render method as react will anyhow re-render once the state is changed.

Comment: This is incorrect if `setState()` is called inside an event handler.

Comment: @probablyup can you elaborate?

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it depends on when it is called. setState() is executed immediately when called inside an event handler. I believe it might also be synchronous before the component has mounted.

Basically every other time it will be called asynchronously.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/setstate-in-reactjs-is-async-or-sync