# setState not working in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to give few dates to state.periods array. But it is not working. My code is as follows.

```
class SmallTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props.startDate)
        this.state = {
            turns: [],
            periods: []
        }
    }

componentDidMount() {
    //calculate years/ months and keep in one array
         const today = new Date();
         var periods1 = [];
         if (this.props.period=="year") { //if year calculate from last year last date
             const lastYearLastDate= new Date(new Date().getFullYear()-1, 11, 31)
             periods1.push(lastYearLastDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(lastYearLastDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+lastYearLastDate.getDate());

             var lastYearFirstDate= new Date(lastYearLastDate.getFullYear()-1,0,1);

             //for the remaining periods
             for (var i=0;i<this.props.numberOfPeriods-1;i++) {
                 periods1.push(lastYearFirstDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(lastYearFirstDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+lastYearFirstDate.getDate());
                 lastYearFirstDate = new Date(lastYearFirstDate.getFullYear()-1,0,1);
             }


         }


        else if (this.props.period=="month") {//if month calculate from last month last date
            var d=new Date(); // current date
            d.setDate(1); // going to 1st of the month
            d.setHours(-1); // going to last hour before this date even started.
            var lastMonthLastDate = d;
            periods1.push(lastMonthLastDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(lastMonthLastDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+lastMonthLastDate.getDate());

            //go to last month  first date
            var lastMonthFirstDate = new Date(lastMonthLastDate.getFullYear(), lastMonthLastDate.getMonth(),1);

            //for the remaining periods
            for (var i=0;i<this.props.numberOfPeriods-1;i++) {
                periods1.push(lastMonthFirstDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(lastMonthFirstDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+lastMonthFirstDate.getDate());

                lastMonthFirstDate=new Date(lastMonthFirstDate.getFullYear(), lastMonthFirstDate.getMonth()-1,1);
            }

        }

console.log(periods1); -->prints  ["2017-12-31", "2016-1-1", "2015-1-1", "2014-1-1"]
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
            return {
                periods: prevState.periods.push(periods1)
            }
        });
        console.log(this.state.periods) --> prints []

    }
render() {

        return ( <div></div>)
}
```

How to get values in periods1 to periods state. I am trying to insert periods1 array into state periods array. Those are strings. Pls suggest where the error might be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setState in reactjs is Async or Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/setstate-in-reactjs-is-async-or-sync)

Comment: `prevState.periods.push(periods1)` does *not* return your array. You need to `push()` and *then* return

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `this.state.periods` to the result of a `push` operation. But `push` returns the new array length, not the array itself. Try this instead:

```
periods: [...prevState.periods, periods1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues.

For the code here:

```
return {
    periods: prevState.periods.push(periods1)
}
```

You never want to mutate state. Instead, you should create a new array object and then add the data, like so:

```
return {
    periods: prevState.periods.concat([periods1])
}
```

Secondly, your console.log is in the wrong place

```
console.log(this.state.periods) --> prints []
```

setState happens *asynchronously* and thus may not finish by the time your `componentDidMount` method returns. Instead, put that console.log inside your `render` function to see the new state.

Answer (score 2):

`push()` doesn't return a value.
You should use:

```
this.setState((prevState)=>{
    let old = prevState.periods.slice();
    old.push(periods1);
    return {
        periods: old
    }
});
```

Comment: You're mutating the state here, never use `push` directly on a state.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect `this.state.periods` to be an array of arrays (`[["2017-12-31", "2016-1-1", "2015-1-1", "2014-1-1"]]`) you can push your array following an immutable pattern using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) :

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
       periods: [...prevState.periods, periods1]
    }), () => { console.log(this.state.periods) } );
```

You can notice the function passed as second param of `setState()` is a callback to execute `console.log()` after the state update.

If you want to push `periods1` **values** in `this.state.periods` you can do this :

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
       periods: [...prevState.periods, ...periods1]
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a copy of your original `state`, so that you can perform `setState` in an immutable fashion.

```
const periods = [...this.state.periods];
periods.push(periods1);
this.setState({periods: periods});
```