# ReactJS: setState value not updating

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I'm trying to update a state value from within a method. When I `.log` above the `setState` the value is correct but afterwards I get an `undefined`. I should be getting the `userObject`. The data is passed to the method correctly, just not sure why the value isn't being set?

```
toggleModal = (user) => {
var userData = {};
if (user === null) {
  userData = {}
} else {
  userData = user
}
this.setState({
  isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
  dataType: 'user',
  user: userData
});
console.log(this.state.user);
}
```

When I pass the value to another component the value is marked as undefined and not null or an empty object.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/setstate-in-reactjs-is-async-or-sync. setState is asynchronous

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings .@stack26  link should work. +1

Comment: None of the links help so it's not a duplicate. I'm still getting an undefined despite your suggestions.

Comment: If this is not longer a duplicate then you need to explain why it is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.setState({
  isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
  dataType: 'user',
  user: userData
},()=>{console.log(this.state.user)});
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks! I am getting an undefined when using the props in a component.