# Set state twice in a single function - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that sets state twice, however - the second `setState` has to occur after 500ms since first `setState` has occured (animation purposes).

Code looks like:

```
const showAnimation = () => {
   this.setState({ hidden: false });

   setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ hidden: true });
   }, 500);
};
```

**However** - if I do it this way, React somehow merges these two `setState`'s into one and my animation doesn't work as expected.

But, if I use a hack:

```
const showAnimation = () => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ hidden: false });
   }, 0);  // ------------------------------> timeout 0

   setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ hidden: true });
   }, 500);
};
```

It works as expected. But still, I don't really like it and Im afraid that it may be some kind of a hack. Is there any better solution for such case? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

As `setState` are async in React you might not get updated state immediately but `setState` gives you `prevState` param in `setState` function to get last updated state so you won't merge state

The syntax goes like this in your case

```
this.setState((prevState) => { hidden: false }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ hidden: !prevState.hidden });
      }, 500);
    });
```

just update your value to the updated state using `prevState`

If I understand your problem correct this should work fine
Please let me know if more clarification required

Answer (score 1):

If you try something like that:

```
const showAnimation = () => {
    this.setState({ hidden: false }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ hidden: true });
      }, 500);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use animations within JS if you are looking to time it without setTimeout. However this may be down to the face that 'setState' is async within react.

similar : 
[Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

However react does expose a callback within setState - this works for me

```
this.setState(
            { hidden : false },
            () => {
                setTimeout(()=>{this.setState({hidden : true})}, 500)
            }
        );
```

Comment: i would def use css or js for the animations, but if not, callback is cleanest way

Comment: it causes warning in the console `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.`

Comment: Usually promises are a good work around for async operations :D

Comment: the setState callback handles async just as well as a promise but with less additional code. The update during an existing state transition is an issue with calling this function in the render function

Answer (score 0):

For rendering performance, react batches calls to `setState` such that sequential calls will be executed together and will often be reflected in the same render cycle. Per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

In order to ensure that the first setState has been executed prior to your second call, you can pass `setState` a callback as the second argument. It's not perfect, but something like the following will ensure that your second call to `setState` will only happen once `hidden: false`.

```
const showAnimation = () => {
this.setState({ hidden: false }, () => setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({ hidden: true });
  }, 500););
};
```