# Why is my array not updated in the state in React?

Tags: reactjs

After calling `this.setState` the `talents` property still holds the old value:

```js
onTalentModalCheckboxChange(e) {
  debugger;
  var talent = JSON.parse(e.target.dataset.talent);
  talent.checked = !talent.checked;

  if (this.maximumSelectedTalentsReached() && talent.checked) return;

  const talentIndex = this.state.talents.findIndex(t => t.Id == talent.Id);
  let updatedTalents = [...this.state.talents];
  updatedTalents[talentIndex] = talent;

  this.setState({ talents: updatedTalents });

  // this method (setSearchResultsTotal) uses this.state.talents, 
  // but the talent that is updated here, is not updated. 
  // It still has the 'old' checked value
  this.setSearchResultsTotal();
}
```

The `talents` property contains a list of Talent objects, which all have the `checked` property. My problem is that when setting the updated talent object

What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe this could help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous meaning the change doesn't happen immediately. So any function that uses state, needs to be called **after** the `setState` call completes. There are two ways to do this: use `componentDidUpdate` to fire off the function if `this.state.talents` is different than `prevState.talents`. Or, use the `setState` callback to call the function:

```
onTalentModalCheckboxChange(e) {
  debugger;
  var talent = JSON.parse(e.target.dataset.talent);
  talent.checked = !talent.checked;

  if (this.maximumSelectedTalentsReached() && talent.checked) return;

  const talentIndex = this.state.talents.findIndex(t => t.Id == talent.Id);
  let updatedTalents = [...this.state.talents];
  updatedTalents[talentIndex] = talent;

  // Only call this.setSearchResultsTotal after state has finished updating
  this.setState({ talents: updatedTalents }, () => this.setSearchResultsTotal(); );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.setState({ talents: updatedTalents }, () => {
  this.setSearchResultsTotal();
});
```

try calling ur method like this , it will work

Comment: For the sake of explanation, what this is doing is registering an anonymous callback to make sure that `setSearchResultsTotal` is called after the state updates.