# onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave behaving opposite as expected in my code - why?

Tags: reactjs, state

In a component `AddWordPartButton`'s class, I initialized a state `isHovered` to `false` and used `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to change its value.

Here's the mapping I want (which seems to me that I've defined in the code):

- `onMouseEnter` ⇒ `isHovered = true`
- `onMouseLeave` ⇒ `isHovered = false`

What happens is the opposite of what I expect to happen and I don't see any reason for this behavior.
Here's the mapping that seems to occur:

- `onMouseEnter` ⇒ `isHovered = false`
- `onMouseLeave` ⇒ `isHovered = true`

I use `AddWordPartButton` in another component with nothing that should be affecting its behavior, calling with this `<AddWordPartButton />` inside a `render` function of the other component - it works perfectly fine except for this.

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react;

class AddWordPartButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isHovered: false,
        };
        this.onMouseEnterHandler = this.onMouseEnterHandler.bind(this);
        this.onMouseLeaveHandler = this.onMouseLeaveHandler.bind(this);
    } 

    onMouseEnterHandler() {
        this.setState({isHovered: true});
        console.log(this.state); //logs false
    }

    onMouseLeaveHandler() {
        this.setState({isHovered: false});
        console.log(this.state); //logs true
    }

    render() {
        <div className={classes.addWordPartButton__Container} 
            onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnterHandler}
            onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeaveHandler}
        >
        </div>


    }

}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, your code is working. Try  `this.setState({isHovered: true}, () => console.log(this.state));` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it's async. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set state is async, use this instead, the callback argument to the setState func will fire after it sets state. It is opposite bc you are always logging one step behind the new state update.

```
onMouseEnterHandler() {
    this.setState(() => ({isHovered: true}), () => console.log(this.state));
}

onMouseLeaveHandler() {
    this.setState(() => ({isHovered: false}), () => console.log(this.state));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it's async.
It solved my issue.

Comment: Saying it is async is not quite accurate. Much of the time it is sync. "[...] This doesn't mean it will always be asynchronous - it mainly means that you just can't depend on it being synchronous." https://stackoverflow.com/a/48438145/2054731

Comment: no it is 100% async, don't confuse people and say it "behaves synchronous" most of the time