# JS unit testing using enzyme: how to wait for setState within component's method to finish before proceeding with test case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have a component `MyComponent` with method `doSomething` that updates a state, and `renderChildren` that renders child components based on these states:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
    this.state = {
      renderChildA: true,
      renderChildB: false,
    };
  }

  doSomething = (params) => {
    // Do something...

    this.setState({ 
      renderChildA: false,
      renderChildB: true,
    });
  }

  renderChildren = () => {
    const { renderChildA, renderChildB } = this.state;
    if (renderChildA) {
      return <ChildComponentA />;
    } else if (renderChildB) {
      return <ChildComponentB />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderChildren()}
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*NOTE: the component is also connected to Redux, but has been simplified.*

For unit testing, I'm calling `doSomething` and verifying that `ChildComponentB` is visible:

```
test('doSomething should trigger ChildComponentB to pop up', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <MyComponent
    ...
    />,
  ).dive();

  wrapper.instane().doSomething(params); // assume params is defined

  const childComponentB = wrapper.find('ChildComponentB');
  expect(childComponentB).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

However, the test case above fails:

```
my-component.test.jsx > Some test group name > doSomething should trigger ChildComponentB to pop up

    expect(received).toHaveLength(length)

    Expected value to have length:
      1
    Received:
      // Some giant JSON object
    recevied.length:
      0

      xxx |    const childComponentB = wrapper.find('ChildComponentB');
      xxx |    expect(childComponentB).toHaveLength(1);
      xxx |  });
```

Based on the logging, I'm seeing that `setState` within `doSomething` is triggered after `expect` statement in the test case. I suspect this is happening since [`setState` is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync), but I don't know a workaround for this (other than `setTimeout`).

Comment: in your test you are actually testing if ChildComponentB is there instead of ChildComponentA

const **childComponentA** = container.find('**ChildComponentB**');

Comment: Yes, I'm checking if `ChildComponentB` is there. The variable name is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a rather simple solution. Use [`Async/Await`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html#async-await):

```
test('doSomething should trigger ChildComponentB to pop up', async() => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <MyComponent
    ...
    />,
  ).dive();

  await wrapper.instane().doSomething(params);

  const childComponentB = wrapper.find('ChildComponentB');
  expect(childComponentB).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually update the component to get the latest state:

```
  wrapper.instance().doSomething(params); // assume params is defined
  wrapper.update(); 
  const childComponentB = container.find('ChildComponentB');
  expect(childComponentB).toHaveLength(1);
```

More info: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html

Comment: I've already tried this, but it results in the same behaviour described in the question. Even with `update()`, the state is still unchanged by the time `expect()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work or not but lets try updating the `doSomething` function as.

```
doSomething = (params) => {
  this.setState({ 
    renderChildA: false,
    renderChildB: true,
  },() => this.renderChildren());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    it('check List component for column list', async () => {
    #ur code for re-render stuff
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0)); // wait for response

    # this will sync ur wrapper with latest tree change
    wrapper = wrapper.update();  
});
```