# LocalStorage not working properly ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have an array set up in a table so that when I click on an icon, a different icon is re-rendered in that specific row. Now I have localstorage setup so that when I refresh the page, the state is maintained. The problem I am having though is if I click 4 icons, 4 different icons are obviously re-rendered but when I refresh the page, the *last* one I click is reverted to its original state so now I only have 3 of the re-rendered icons. How do I fix this?

```
import React from 'react';
import StarBorder from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorder';
import Star from '@material-ui/icons/Star';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        var newData = [];

        if (localStorage.getItem('new')) {
            newData =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('new'));
        }

        this.state = {
          data: newData,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        if (!localStorage.getItem('new')) {
            axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true')
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;
                this.setState({  data: data.map(x => ({...x, starIcon: true})) })
            })
        }
    }

    handleClick = (i) => {

        this.setState(prevState => ({
          data: prevState.data.map((x, key) => (key === i ? {...x, starIcon: !x. starIcon} : x))
        }));

          localStorage.setItem('new', JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
      }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Icon</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.data.map((n, i) => {
                    return (
                        <tr>
                        <td> <span onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}> {n.starIcon ? <StarBorder/> : <Star /> } </span> </td>
                        <td>{n.name}</td>
                        <td>{n.current_price}</td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` is async, so you when you set items to local storage you may still capture previous state. To fix it, use `setState`'s callback function to make sure the state is updated when you set the items:

```
  handleClick = (i) => {
   this.setState(prevState => ({
     data: prevState.data.map((x, key) => (key === i ? {
       ...x,
       starIcon: !x.starIcon
     } : x))
   }), () => {
     localStorage.setItem('new', JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change handleClick function, Because before setState set its state, local storage setitem method getting called so. 
So you have to use callback function of setState method

[Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)

```
handleClick = (i) => {
   this.setState(prevState => ({
     data: prevState.data.map((x, key) => (key === i ? {
       ...x,
       starIcon: !x.starIcon
     } : x))
   }), () => {
     localStorage.setItem('new', JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
   });
 }
```