# Mutation called returns false, but the object is created in DB

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, mutation

I've built a modal in ReactJS and added handleClick on submit button.

```
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const res = await createApp({variables: {id, name, url}});
    console.log('response' + res)
    console.log('loading' + loading);
    console.log('called' + called);
    console.log('error' + error)
    console.log('data' + data)
  }
```

On the first click, I'm getting

```
 response[object Object]
 loadingfalse
 calledfalse
 errorundefined
 dataundefined
```

On the second click, I'm getting

```
response[object Object]
loadingfalse
calledtrue
errorundefined
data[object Object]
```

However, the right object is being created in DB on the first click!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your question how you're getting the `loading`, `error`, `called` and `data` variables, but I'll assume it's from the `useMutation` hook. However, if you're using the `Mutation` component, the following explanation still applies.

The `useMutation` hook returns an array with a function and a `MutationResult` object, which includes properties like `loading`, `error`, `called` and `data`. These properties are exposed as a convenience in order to easily update your component's UI, however, they are just regular [component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html). As such, any changes to them are *asynchronous*, just like with [setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync).

In other words, you can call and await `createApp` and as a result of doing so, the aforementioned properties will be *eventually* updated. However, there is no guarantee that they will updated *before* the Promise returned by `createApp` resolves. So even though you're awaiting the call to `createApp`, the values of each of those properties have not updated yet. If, instead of logging them inside the click handler, you instead render them inside your component, you will seem them change appropriately.

If you need to access the data returned by your operation inside the click handler, you can do so from the value of the resolved Promise:

```
const { data, error } = await createApp({variables: {id, name, url}});

// Note: loading and called are not exposed similarly because that would be moot --
// if the promise has resolved, the function was called and you're no longer loading
```

Comment: Thank you for such an awesome explanation, Daniel! That's exactly the issue!