# onClick loop happens only once per click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `label`, which has `onClick` callback:

```
<label className="cursor-pointer" onClick={loadExisting}>
  Click me
</label>
```

`loadExisting` function, `fetch`'es data from api, and passses it to `parseData` function.

```
 const loadExisting = () => {
    fetch("/api/v.1.0/events", { mode: "no-cors" })
      .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
          console.log("Something is wrong");
          return;
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        if (!data) {
          return;
        }
        parseEvents(data);
      });
  };
```

In this function, I am trying to store only those events, which's `title`s are unique:

```
const parseEvents = data => {
    if (data) {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (titlesArray.indexOf(data[i].title) < 0) {
          setTitlesArray([...titlesArray, data[i].title]);
          setEvents([...events, data[i]]);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Basically my idea is to set all the unique titles into `titlesArray` and if event's `title` is unique, I add it to both `titlesArray` and `events`.

**Problem**: This only works if I keep clicking on that `label`. With first click `events.length` is equal to 0, second click- equal to 1, third click- equal to 2, etc. **Why it does not parse all events at once? So after 1 click I would have ~10 events that have unique titles.**

Comment: You need to elaborate on this question. "This only works if I keep clicking on that `label`.": because the event gets fired `onClick` only.

Comment: @AkshitMehra, yes, but I would expect, it would parse all the events, it got from the API, not a single one.

When page loads, `events` is empty, if I click on label, I get back 19 events from API. But if I `console.log(events)`, before render, after I click label, `events` have only 1 object inside it. If I click it for second time- `events` have two objects inside it. 

I would expect, after clicking a label:
1) Request to API retrieves 19 events
2) ALL the events get parsed
3) I have ~10 events that have unique titles in `events` state.

Comment: fetch(url).then(res=> res.json()).then(data => parseEvents(data)) you should try.

Comment: Can you post the code of `loadExisting()` function that you're calling?

Comment: @AkshitMehra , updated original post with `loadExisting()` function

Comment: What does the data you get back from the API look like? And are you using class based components or functional components?

Comment: @MattOestreich, functional.

Data from API is an array consisting of objects. Each object is an event with it's values.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync) and `setTitlesArray` and `setEvents` are likely to call `setState`.

So in your case, since you don't update `titlesArray` and `events`, the most likely is that you will only observe the last elem added
(`data[data.length-1]`)

The fix is to simply call `setState` once.

```
data.forEach(d => {
  if (titlesArray.includes(d.title) {
    titlesArray.push(d.title)
    events.push(d)
  }
})
//I slice 0 to copy, but maybe it is not necessary if your function does it already
setTitlesArray(titlesArray.slice(0))
setEvents(events.slice(0))
```

---

nb: looking for existence in an array (titlesArray) is less efficient than using a Set. You should consider if you have a lot of titles