# React - useState hook access state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datepicker, calendar

I have the following states:

```
let [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(new Date().getMonth());
const [checkIn_month, setCheckInMonth] = useState(null);
```

I have an `click event listener` assigned **directly** to `JSX's` element `tbody`. Using `event delegation` to click on the `td elements`.

And in the following function if i click on a day that is in the *previous month* i need to decrement the `currentMonth state` and after that to set the new value of `currentMonth` in the `setCheckInMonth` state.

The **problem** is:

When i use the `setCheckInMonth(currentMonth)` state hook it gives the old value, not the new one.

```
let [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(new Date().getMonth());
const [checkIn_month, setCheckInMonth] = useState(null);

const selectDate = e => {

 if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {

   if (e.target.classList.contains('previous-month-day')) {
    setCurrentMonth(currentMonth => currentMonth - 1);
    setCheckInMonth(currentMonth);
   }
  }
}
```

What if i do something like this:

```
setCurrentMonth(currentMonth => currentMonth - 1);
setCheckInMonth(currentMonth - 1);
```

Is this a correct way of doing it ?

Comment: How do you get your value? Are you trying to get it from the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setState()` is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087156/9041122). It doesn't immediately mutate(update) the object. So doing this -

```
setCurrentMonth(currentMonth => currentMonth - 1);
```

doesn't mean that `currentMonth` has the updated value that you can use immediately in the next line.

What you can do is -

```
const newCurrentMonth = currentMonth - 1;
// now use this newCurrentMonth to update the state.
setCurrentMonth(newCurrentMonth );
setCheckInMonth(newCurrentMonth );
```

Comment: Ok so the last answer that i post it in the question is correct ?

`setCurrentMonth(currentMonth => currentMonth - 1);`
`setCheckInMonth(currentMonth - 1);`

Comment: @grecdev that can't be said for sure. As I mentioned in my answer - `setState` is async. So if in some cases currentMonth is updated right away, then `checkInMonth` would have wrong value. This case is very highly unlikely. But it can happen theoratically. So I would not suggest that approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `checkIn_month` using the current value of `currentMonth`, you can't rely on `currentMonth`'s value being updated immediately, as `setState` calls are asynchronous. You can instead move your call to `setCheckInMonth` within the callback passed to `setCurrentMonth` so that you have access to the current value of `currentMonth`.

For example:

```js
setCurrentMonth(currentMonth => {
    const newCurrentMonth = currentMonth - 1;
    setCheckInMonth(newCurrentMonth);
    return newCurrentMonth;
});
```