# React Native Passing data to another screen using NavigationEvents

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a FlatList that would render 3 rows of data containing the respective dataSource. In this example, I have created 3 rows of Feedback data.

I would like to pass the feedbackLogId of the row I pressed to another screen, which will show in depth details of the Feedback according to the feedackLogId.

### FeedbackLogs.js

This is how the data looks like that will generate three FlatList rows. since the data is fetched, it is set to the state of dataSource.

```
dataSource = [{
  "feedbackLogId": 1,
  "name": "Test1",
  "comment": "Hello",
}, {
  "feedbackLogId": 2,
  "name": "Test2",
  "type": "Hi",
}, {
  "feedbackLogId": 3,
  "name": "Test3",
  "type": "Morning",
}]
```

This is the onPress method of my FlatList where it would navigate me to the details screen.

`onPress={() => this.navigateFeedbackDetails()>`

Upon pressing the button, `navigateFeedbackDetails` will be called.

```
navigateFeedbackDetails = () => {
    this.setState({
      feedbackLogId: this.state.dataSource[0].feedbackLogId
    }, () => this.props.navigation.navigate('FeedbackDetails', {value: this.state.feedbackLogId}))
  }
```

### FeedbackDetails.js

The problem lies here where I would be successfully navigated to FeedbackDetails screen. Here, I would `import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation'` for me to be able to access NavigationEvents. Then in render,

```
render() {
        willFocusAction = (payload) => {
            let params = payload.state.params;
            let value = params.value;
            this.setState({ feedbackId: value });
            console.log(this.state.feedbackId);
        }
        
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <NavigationEvents
                    onWillFocus={this.willFocusAction}
                />
                <View style={styles.listView}>
                  <Text style={styles.label}>Name </Text>
                  <Text style={[styles.name, styles.name]}>{this.state.feedbackId}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
    )
}
```

I am not able to console.log the data, as well as show the state of the feedbackId, it just give me no response at all. I have also updated react-navigation as some say that it could be causing the problem. I am still unable to solve the problem and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

## Edit:

This might be an issue with my navigation as my FeedbackLogs screen is inside a TopTabNavigator.

This will help create 2 tabs on top of the screen for me to switch between Logs and Pending pages. Since I also have a bottomTabNavigator, this is the only way that could be done.

```
const HomeTopTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
//Feedback Details will be called on both screens in the future but I am testing on Pending for now
  Logs: {
    screen: Logs
  },
  Pending: {
    screen: Pending,
  }
```

After creating the TopTab, I store the screens inside the HomeStack. It is also where I call the FeedbackDetails screen as well.

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  HomeTopTabNavigator: HomeTopTabNavigator,
  FeedbackDetails: {
    screen: FeedbackDetails
  }
})
```

I am unsure whether this calling the screen here would mess up the passing of data, hence I would like to leave this here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: in the render method, you console.log(this.state.feedbackId). What comes out when you console.log(payload)?

Comment: Did you make sure that you are sending the expected data through navigation? I mean, I don't think `this.state.feedbackLogId` is being updated before navigating. I'd rather send `this.state.dataSource[0].feedbackLogId` instead

Comment: Side Note: setState is asynchronous. So setting and logging state right after might not work. you can add a callback to the second param of setState like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40408976/1309377 and then call the console log there. This assumes you have the right state variable being set.

Comment: @CoryBaker the terminal is not displaying anything when im console.log() them. I feel like ```willFocusAction``` is not being called at all.

Comment: Is it possible that I might have messed up the screens in Navigation.js as I am working with around 10 screens with different navigators such as Drawer, BottomTab, TabNavigators and Stacks.

Comment: I've also edited the question to include how i made my navigation. This could be one of the mistakes that I have made. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access params using `navigation.getParam`/`navigation.state.params`.

When yo do:

```js
navigation.navigate('FeedbackDetails', {value: this.state.feedbackLogId}))
```

You can access it in `FeedbackDetails` screen like:

```js
const value = navigation.getParam('value')
```

`NavigationEvents` is unrelated to params.