# If setState() is not web api then but asynchrouns, how is it run begind the scenes

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and came across this question [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync) and someone called "Sachin" answered that setState() is not web api. Then, I asked myself if it is not web api but asynchronous, how is it actually run? That is, if something is called asynchrounsly then it is logical that it is run via callback so as not to block the main stack. So, the question is if setState() is not web api, how is it called asynchronously?

Comment: If you read the entire answer of "Sachin", you have your answer

Comment: @JonathanHamel, I did but couldn't get it properly, please can you kindly clarify?

Comment: `setState` isn't *called* asynchronously, it's *run* asynchronously. There are a number of reasons for this (e.g., batching, avoiding re-renders). The implementing code is somewhat complex; there's a walk-through https://github.com/numbbbbb/read-react-source-code/blob/master/03-how-setstate-works-part-1.md, https://github.com/numbbbbb/read-react-source-code/blob/master/03-how-setstate-works-part-2.md, and https://github.com/numbbbbb/read-react-source-code/blob/master/05-how-setstate-works-part-3.md.

Comment: @DaveNewton, thank you Dave for your kind comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not `setState` but the meaning of the word **asynchronous**. The word asynchronous literally means: *not existing or occurring at the same time*.

Let's say we have this pseudo code:

```
fnOne()
fnTwo()    // this is async
fnThree()
```

The flow of execution of our pseudo code would be `fnOne`, `fnThree`, `fnTwo`. Because `fnTwo` is async, it is not happening at the same time as `fnOne` and `fnThree`. It is happening later.

---

To answer your question about `setState`. You call it but React doesn't go and update the state, run the diff algorithm, and replace the DOM, at the moment of the call. React does all of that eventually, at a later time, asynchronously.