# How can I assign an array to a state variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a function that looks like this:

```
select(e) {
    let { selectedItems } = this.state;

    let arr: number[] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) arr = [...arr, i];

    this.setState(
      {
        selectedItems: arr,
      }
    );
  console.log(selectedItems);
  }
```

But when I try to `console.log(selectedItems)`, all I get is an empty array. When I `console.log(arr)`, I get the correct output I'm looking for -- an array of length 2. What might be going on here and how can I assign `selectedItems` to the value of `arr`?

Comment: Where/when do you log? (I don't understand your sample code.) `setState` is async. Being an array isn't relevant; `setState` doesn't care about types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A {
  select(e) {
    let { selectedItems } = this.state;
    let arr: number[] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) arr = [...arr, i];
    this.setState({
      selectedItems: arr
    }, function callback() {
      console.log(this.state) // will have updated value
    });
    console.log(selectedItems); // wont print anything, coz u never assign
    selectedItems = arr;
    console.log(selectedItems); // will have updated value
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, how silly of me, I just realized that this is what I was missing all along

Answer (score 1):

`setState` takes a callback function.  Try the following:

```
  select(e) {
    let { selectedItems } = this.state;

    let arr: number[] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) arr = [...arr, i];

    this.setState({
      selectedItems: arr,
    }, function(){
        console.log(this.state);
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

Comment: This won't work, you need to bind the `this` keyword to that callback function.

Comment: check the answer below.  not binded and appears to work