# Order in which useEffect is called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When using multiple useEffect is there and order in which they are called?

Consider the following code

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(2);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("A");
    setX(1);
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("B");
    console.log(x);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {x}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Console output is

```
A
B
2
```

Why x is 2 and not 1?

Comment: because `setX` is async

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync This is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect are called in the order in which they are written in the code and depending on which useEffect's dependency leads to its execution

Also **state updates are async** and **and any use of `setX`  or other state updaters will only be updated once all executions of useEffects are completed** which is why `console.log(x)` shows 2 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

Initial useEffect are called in the order they appear in your code. For example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect-1')
}, [])
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect-2')
}, [])
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect-3')
}, [])
```

Output:

```sh
useEffect-1
useEffect-2
useEffect-3
```

However, further calls will depend on which variable gets updated