# React API fetch returning an empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am having problems of receiving the data from a API fetch,
I am guessing data might received after the `console.log()`?

How can I fix this?

```
fetch("https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/games?title=batman")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data[0])
      })
```

This code return a object data straight away

```
fetch("https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/games?title=batman")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({api: data[0] ,loading:false})
      })
      console.log(this.state.api)
```

However, I'll need to save the fetched data into the state, but when I call it after saving it, it returns a empty object, that influences me to print the data to UI.

Help....

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous, hence if you try to console it immediately it is empty. More can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

state is updated asynchronously. If you want to see the updated state immediately after updating it, pass a second argument to `setState` function which is a callback function which runs after the state has updated

```
this.setState({api: data[0] ,loading:false}, () => console.log(this.state))
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for helping, I am not only trying to see it, because its running asynchronously, when I am trying to print it to the the screen in render(), its undefined, how can I print it after its actually fullly loaded?

Comment: inside render function, check if `this.state.api` is defined and print it only if it is defined

Comment: Yeah, Now i got it, you are a legend bro!

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to resolve a promise and the console log is likely to be executed before the promise returns, try to following code to fetch your data:

```
fetch("https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/games?title=batman")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({api: data[0] ,loading:false},() => console.log(this.state.api))
      });
```

This always executes the log line after setting the state.