# Why my state is undefined even though I'm setting it

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I'm new to React and Redux. I would like to ask why if I'm setting an object in a setState when I try to use it or show it in the console is undefined.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from 'axios';
import ProductImage from './Sections/ProductImage';
import ProductInfo from './Sections/ProductInfo';

function DetailProduct (props){
    const productId = props.match.params.productId
    const [Product, setProduct] = useState()

    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/products/'+productId)
            .then(response =>{
                setProduct(response.data)
                console.log('state '+Product._id)
            })
    }, [])

    return (

        <div className="postPage" style={{width: '100%', padding: '3rem 4rem'}}>       
            <div style={{display:'flex',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <h1>{Product._id}</h1>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <Row gutter={[16, 16]}>
                <Col lg={12} xs={24}>
                    <ProductImage />
                </Col>
                <Col lg={12} xs={24}>
                    <ProductInfo />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    )

}

export default DetailProduct
```

When the page loads it says that Product is undefined, even though it's suppose to have an object. When I console.log what response.data has it shows me the information that product would need to have. Sorry for bad english and thank you.

Comment: setState in React is async funtion. This can provide more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when the component renders the first time the axios request hasn't finished running. At that point, `Product` will be whatever you set as the default. In this case you haven't set a default for `Product` so it is undefined. You can do that in useState like so `const [Product, setProduct] = useState({})`

Another way you could solve this is wrap your component in an if statement that checks to see if `Product` has been set yet.

```
{Product && (
  <div>your component here</div>
)}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much :) can I ask what changes putting {} insise useState() ? does it initialize it with a null value ?

Comment: it is the default value for `Product` (empty object). Let's say you were using a number and you wanted it to start at 0, it would be `useState(0)`

Comment: Can you set this as the solution if it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

buddy!

Like [Tony Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13345964/tony-nguyen) said that setState in React is async function. But if you want to do something when state(your `Product`) changed, you can set up another `useEffect` to do this:

```js
useEffect(()=>{

  // Do somethings if you want to do when Product changed

}, [Product])
```

Please let me know, if you have any questions. :)

Comment: For now I just want to reference it in the return function, where "{Product.id}" is, but if I understand correctly it will still be undefined it is asynced

Comment: Maybe you need to set up initial value of your state(Produce), like this `useState({ _id: defaultID })`.