# I've got some problems with changing state

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**I want to render numbers from state, but when I click button nothing happens. How could I fix that?**

```
class App extends Component {
        state = {
            hours: 0,
            min: 0,
            sec: 0
        }

handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        sec: this.state.sec++
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <main className="time-change">
                <form>
                    <h2>{this.state.hours}:{this.state.min}:{this.state.sec}</h2> 
                </form>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>^</button>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: `this.state.sec++` mutates state, and returns the value before update (see [Postfix increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)). Instead change to `this.state.sec + 1`.

Comment: Along with this, you are also missing a constructor, which should call the super() function in order to properly inherit from the Component parent class.

Comment: Agree with @BrianThompson, because `this.state.sec` is a mutates state, if you want to update state you can use `this.state.sec + 1`. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.sec++` mutates the state, and we should never mutate the state directly (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

Also note, the `setState` is asynchronous, and such a code with a counter update may fail.
You may find a good explanation about its asynchronous nature [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087156/4539076) and in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

With this in mind, it's a good practice to use the form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object like:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        sec: prevState.sec + 1
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `this.state.sec++` will first return the actual value of `this.state.sec` and then increment it's value. Also if your new state depends on the old state it is [recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) to use an updater function in the `setState`

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    sec: prevState.sec + 1
});
```