# How do componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount works?

Tags: reactjs

I have an example here with a simple state called counter. In the componentDidMount, I am getting 0 instead of 3 during console.log and during unmount, I am getting the counter number from button click instead of 0. I am confused as to how does it really works? Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class TestNumber extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {counter: 0}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Mount Called')
        this.setState({counter:3})
        console.log(this.state.counter)
      }
      
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.setState({counter:0})
        console.log('Unmount Called')       
        console.log(this.state.counter)
      }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.state.counter}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Click me
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TestNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to posed answer.

The problem here is not with life cycle methods but the problem is `state`.
In react state can be asynchronous sometimes.

React Doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Supporting article: https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3

In general we should assume that react `state` is asynchronous and should not rely on it immediately.
Following code will print correct `console.log`.

```
this.setState({count: 3}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.counter)
});
```

Bottom line

> React state can be asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

It is not about how those two life-cycle methods work, it is about the `setState` being async in React, which means that the sate value won't be modified right after you call `setState` and that is why you get the old values from the console.log.

[Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36085726/5913039)

The following example will give you the right results.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({counter:3}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.counter);
        });
        
        console.log(this.state.counter)
    }
      
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.setState({counter:0}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.counter);
        });

        console.log('Unmount Called');      
    }
```