# setState didn't update the set value in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state-management

Here is the code by which I try to update the state values. I wasn't able to figure out why my state didn't get updated. I added all the respective console values at each line of code.

```
handleFilter=(event)=>
  {
    console.log(this.state.answerStatus) // Before update 'all'
    let val= event.target.value === "answered";
    console.log(val); // true or false
    this.setState({answerStatus:val});
    console.log(this.state.answerStatus); // 'all'
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React `setState` is asynchronous, which means that the sate value won't be modified right after you call `setState` and that is why you get the old values from the console.log.

[Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36085726/5913039)

[React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

```
handleFilter = (event) => {
    console.log(this.state.answerStatus) // Before update 'all'

    let val= event.target.value === "answered";

    console.log(val); // true or false

    this.setState({answerStatus:val}, () => {
       console.log(this.state.answerStatus);
    });
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

State updates are [async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

To see updated value after setState, use second argument which takes a callback function and issue console log over there.

```js
handleFilter = (event) => {
  console.log(this.state.answerStatus); // Before update 'all'
  let val = event.target.value === "answered";
  console.log(val); // true or false
  this.setState({ answerStatus: val }, () =>
    console.log(this.state.answerStatus)
  );
};
```