# JSON data from firebase using object.entries

Tags: reactjs

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udxjN.jpg)The images shows my data stored in Firebase,it is a Json data.

Error is type Error: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined,
what I am doing wrong???

I want to access date from it, on clicking button  show_data , date should be returned,but on the user screen.

I am unable  to print it on console and user screen

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"; //, { useState }
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    getData: "Date"
  };

  reloadHandler = () => {
    axios.get("https://loco-97cba.firebaseio.com/.json").then((res) => {
      const arrayObj = Object.entries(res.data).map((e) => [e[0]]);
      const arrayObj1 = Object.entries(res.data).map((e) => [e[1]]);
      console.log(arrayObj);
      console.log(arrayObj1);
      this.setState({
        getData: arrayObj1[1].date
      });
      console.log( "date", this.state.getData)
      // }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.reloadHandler();
          }}
        >
          GET_DATA
        </button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div style={{border:"black 1px solid",height:"100px"}} >{this.state.getData}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: are you sure, that API call is returning `res` at all? Try console.logging after to see the `res` object.

Comment: yes ,, just checked , res is returning a object, amd res.data is returning the data i need

Comment: Can you put a dummy data to test?`

Comment: The problem is , i m unable to access , print date from the data i stored

Comment: yes, but where are you using `date` in your code. I don't see any mention of the `date`.

Comment: sir i edited the question , i also put a url , at which you have a dummy data, but anyways , thank you very much :)

Comment: in the handler, at the  this.setstate arrayobj[1].date

Comment: are you trying to get all the dates from the .json file and set it in state?

Comment: Yes sir , all the data , like clicked , date, all of them , I just tried to get one of them , but failed to do so

Comment: [Check this out sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-leaf-dxhoh?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: you used object..values!!... if we want to get the array , whole array then we have to use object.entries!!! then??

Comment: you want only the dates, right?

Comment: Please let my doubt be solved, through object.values we can only convert one data at a time ,right?

Comment: Object.values is not for array?? correct??

Comment: [Check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#:~:text=Description-,Object.,values%20of%20the%20object%20manually.)

I have absolutely no clue what you're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below statement will not log your dates into the console. Because `setState` will take time to actually reflects the values.

```
console.log( "date", this.state.getData)
```

Instead what you can do is move that `console.log` into the `render` method so you can see the updated values each time.
One more thing you are not able to see the result on the webpage because your state `this.state.getData` is an array.

```
<div style={{border:"black 1px solid",height:"100px"}} >{this.state.getData}</div>
```

If you want to keep it as an array then you can `map` over it and print the data like this.

```
{this.state && this.state.getData.map(date => <div style={{border:"black 1px solid",height:"100px"}} >{date}</div>)}
```

Otherwise, just try this -

```
<div style={{border:"black 1px solid",height:"100px"}} >{this.state.getData[0]}</div>
```

See this -

- [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries