# Why is this.setState() not setting my state object?

Tags: reactjs, state

React newbie here, so please be kind. I've got an object called `results` which is a fairly large object, containing a number of smaller objects. I've been able to ascertain that it's coming through in the `componentDidMount()` hook, but after going through the code in the hook, I've come to find that the population of a separate state object to the same value of `results` isn't working.

```
  state = {
    homeDesignNameText: "",
    resultsPrime: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      results,
    } = this.props;

    console.log(">>MNTR", results);

    if (results &&
      results.status !== 404 &&
      results.items &&
      results.items.length) {

        console.log(">>BEEP");

      if(!this.state.resultsPrime.items) {
        console.log(">>BOOP");

        this.setState({
          resultsPrime: {...results}
        });
        console.log(">>BEEP2", this.state.resultsPrime);
      }
    }
  }
```

When I run the page containing these, I do get `>>MNTR` coming through in console.log() with the value of the `results` object. I then get `>>BEEP` and `>>BOOP` come through but once `>>BEEP2` comes through in console, the only thing that comes out is `{}`.

One would assume that if `>>BOOP` is reached that the `this.setState()` call is also made, but it doesn't appear to be the case. What exactly am I doing wrong and how do I fix this to ensure that `this.state.resultsPrime` also contains the value of `results`?

Comment: You should check docs about "setstate callback" to understand state

Comment: Setstate operation is asynchronous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync#:~:text=Yes%2C%20setState()%20is%20asynchronous.&text=React%20does%20not%20guarantee%20that,command%20to%20update%20the%20component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated state isn't being consoled because state changes are asynchronous .
To get the updated state you can log it using a callback as:

```
  this.setState({
          resultsPrime: {...results}
        },()=> console.log(">>BEEP2", this.state.resultsPrime));
```

Here the console.log will be executed only once the *resultsPrime* state got updated.
You can read more about state change callbacks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)