# setState not maintaining set value after value set with Callback

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on an application where I multiple some values and use the sum on a computation a bit further. I quickly realized that `this.setState` wasnt working and I saw a callback being said to use a callback so I used `this.setState({ estAlumTxt: estLBCarbonAl }, () => {` however something strange is still happening. If I display the estAlumTxt variable in the console it's correct but if I display it lower down, it no longer has it's value set. This is my code.

```
calWasteCarbon = (event) => { 

    if (`${this.state.reAlumDrop}` === '1') {
        const estLBCarbonAl = (1 * -89.38);


         //this.setState({ estAlumTxt: estLBCarbonAl }
        this.setState({ estAlumTxt: estLBCarbonAl }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.estAlumTxt) // Returns the correct value set
        })        } else {
  
        this.setState({ estAlumTxt: 0 })
    }
    if (`${this.state.recPlasDrop}` === '1') {
        const estLBCarbonPlas = (1 * -35.56);
        this.setState({ estPlasTxt: estLBCarbonPlas })
    } else {
        this.setState({ estPlasTxt: 0 })
    }
    alert(this.state.estAlumTxt); //Alerted value is wrong.
```

Even if console.log reads out estAlumTxt correctly, the alert has it wrong. Gr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)

Comment: The main clue here is that the `alert` is happening *before* the `console.log`.  The former happens immediately, the latter happens asynchronously after the state has been set.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value

Comment: @David I posted the question because despite using the callback I still don't get the desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls to this.setState are asynchronous, meaning that they do not occur synchronously at the time they are called, but may occur at a later time.

This means, that while your function is executing, `state.estAlumTxt` hasn't been updated yet when you call the alert function.

Let's refactor your function a bit so that we only need to call setState once.

First lets extract those number consts out of the function, and I would advise putting them outside the component. There is no need to recalculate those consts every time the function is called.

Then lets create a `stateChange` variable where we can add the properties that we want to conditionally change. After we check the conditions, lets call setState, and alert the value of the `stateChange.estAlumTxt`

```js
const estLBCarbonAl = 1 * -89.38;
const estLBCarbonPlas = 1 * -35.56;

calWasteCarbon = (event) => {
  const stateChange = {};

  if (`${this.state.reAlumDrop}` === '1') {
    stateChange.estAlumTxt = estLBCarbonAl;
  } else {
    stateChange.estAlumTxt = 0;
  }

  if (`${this.state.recPlasDrop}` === '1') {
    stateChange.estPlasTxt = estLBCarbonPlas;
  } else {
    stateChange.estPlasTxt = 0;
  }

  this.setState(stateChange);
  alert(stateChange.estAlumTxt);
};
```