# can't use state value right after setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently i'm doing a quiz composed by multiple categories that can be chosen by the user and i wanna check if the user responded to all questions. For doing that, i compared the number of questions he answered with the number of questions gived by the api response. The problem is that i have an "submit answers" button at the end of the last question, with that onClick function:

```
const sendAnswers = (e, currentQuiz) => {
        setQuizzes({...quizzes, [currentQuiz]:answers});
        setAnswers([])


        var answeredToAllQuestions = true
        
        DataState.map(function (quiz) {
            if(quiz.category in quizzes){
                if(Object.keys(quiz.questions).length !== Object.keys(quizzes[quiz.category]).length){
                    answeredToAllQuestions=false;
                }
            }
        }); 

        if(answeredToAllQuestions === false){
            setAlertTrigger(1);
        }
        else{
            setNumber(number+1);
        }
    
}
```

in that function i use setState on this line: `setQuizzes({...quizzes, [currentQuiz]:answers});` to upload the answers he checked on the last question before checking if he answered to all questions. The problem is that state of quizzes is not updated imediatly and it s not seen by the if condition.

I really don't know how am i supposed to update the state right after setting it because, as i know, react useState updates the state at the next re-render and that causes trouble to me..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)

Comment: No, because literally everyone tells me "setState is Async" and i already know that..I tried to modify my code like this: ```setQuizzes({...quizzes, [currentQuiz]:answers}, () => #CHECKING THINGS )); ``` to check right after the state is updated but it won t work..:(

Comment: @MihaiEne [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875/697154) is the answer you should be reading. As you stated yourself, it's completely misguided to blame the *async* nature of `setState` for the observed behavior. Because incidentally it would be the same if `setState` were in fact *sync*. What you're experiencing is a [*closure problem*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/697154), and you need to deal with that accordingly.

Comment: Also `useState`'s updater != `this.setState`. It does not accept a second parameter callback like `setState` does, so your function is just getting ignored.

Comment: A simple solution would be to store the new value in a variable first. `const newQuizzes = {...quizzes, [currentQuiz]:answers}` then `setQuizzes(newQuizzes)` then use `newQuizzes` instead of `quizzes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that `quizzes` will be equal to `{...quizzes, [currentQuiz]:answers}` (after `setQuizzes` will set it), there is no reason to use `quizzes` in if condition. Replace it with a local var and problem will be solved.

```
const sendAnswers = (e, currentQuiz) => {
    let futureValueOfQuizzes = {...quizzes, [currentQuiz]:answers}
    setQuizzes(futureValueOfQuizzes);
    setAnswers([])


    var answeredToAllQuestions = true
    
    DataState.map(function (quiz) {
        if(quiz.category in futureValueOfQuizzes){
            if(Object.keys(quiz.questions).length !== Object.keys(quizzes[quiz.category]).length){
                answeredToAllQuestions=false;
            }
        }
    }); 

    if(answeredToAllQuestions === false){
        setAlertTrigger(1);
    }
    else{
        setNumber(number+1);
    }

}
```

I would like to take this opportunity to say that these type of problems appear when you use React state for your BI logic. Don't do that! Much better use a local var defined in components body:

```
const Component = () => {
   const [myVar , setMyVar] = useState();
   let myVar = 0;   
   ...           
}
```

If `myVar` is used only for BI logic, use the second initialization, never the first!

Of course sometimes you need a var that is in BI logic and in render (so the state is the only way). In that case set the state properly but for script logic use a local var.

Comment: Thank you! I used a local variable and everything works now :D

Comment: @MihaiEne happy to ear that. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 0):

You have to either combine the `useState` hook with the `useEffect` or update your `sendAnswers` method to perform your control flow through an intermediary variable:

- Using a temporary variable where next state is stored:

  ```
    const sendAnswers = (e, currentQuiz) => {
        const newQuizzes = {...quizzes, [currentQuiz]:answers};

        let answeredToAllQuestions = true

        DataState.map(function (quiz) {
            if(quiz.category in newQuizzes){
                if (Object.keys(quiz.questions).length !== Object.keys(newQuizzes[quiz.category]).length){
                    answeredToAllQuestions = false;
                }
            }
        }); 

        setQuizzes(newQuizzes);
        setAnswers([]);
        if (answeredToAllQuestions === false) {
            setAlertTrigger(1);
        } else {
            setNumber(number+1);
        }

  }
  ```
- Using the `useEffect` hook:

  ```
    const sendAnswers = (e, currentQuiz) => {
        setQuizzes({...quizzes, [currentQuiz]:answers});
        setAnswers([]);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let answeredToAllQuestions = true

        DataState.map(function (quiz) {
            if(quiz.category in quizzes){
                if (Object.keys(quiz.questions).length !== Object.keys(quizzes[quiz.category]).length){
                    answeredToAllQuestions = false;
                }
            }
        });

        if (answeredToAllQuestions === false) {
            setAlertTrigger(1);
        } else {
            setNumber(number+1);
        }
    }, [quizzes]);
  ```