# React: How to update a state prior to another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a state variable called `list` that updates when `setList` is called. `SetList` lives under the function `AddToList`, which adds a value to the existing values in the `list.` As of this moment, the function `handleList` executes prior to the state variable `setList` even though I have `setList` added prior to the function `handleList`. What I am trying to achieve is for the `setList` to update its list prior to running the `handleList`. Could you provide insights on how to fix this?

If you want to test the code, https://codesandbox.io/s/asynchronous-test-mp2fq?file=/Form.js

```
export default function Form() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const addToList = (name) => {
    let newDataList = list.concat(name);
    setList(newDataList);
    console.log("List: ", list);
    handleList();
  };

  const handleList = async () => {
    console.log("Handle List Triggered");
    await axios
      // .put("", list)
      .get("https://api.publicapis.org/entries")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Response: ", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  };

  return (
    <AutoComplete
      name="list"
      label="Add to List"
      onChange={(events, values) => {
        addToList(values.title);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[image]

As you can tell, the `get response` is made prior to updating the list.

Comment: `What I am trying to achieve is for the setList to update its list prior to running the handleList` - this is the definition of `useEffect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do with the updated list, but you know what the new list will be, so you can just pass that around if you need it immediately.

```
  const addToList = (name) => {
    let newDataList = list.concat(name);
    setList(newDataList);
    console.log("List: ", list);
    handleList(newDataList);
  };

  const handleList = async (list) => {
    console.log("Handle List Triggered");
    await axios
      // .put("", list)
      .get("https://api.publicapis.org/entries")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Response: ", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  };
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I was trying to put an updated `list` using REST API, as you've already figured out.

Comment: To be clear, this is what `useEffect` is for.

Answer (score 2):

React's `useEffect` hook has an array of dependencies that it watches for changes. While a lot of the time it's used with no dependencies (i.e. no second parameter or empty array) to replicate the functionality of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, you may be able to use that to trigger `handleList` by specifying `list` as a dependency like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  handleList(list);
}, [list]);
```

I think there may be a redundant request when page loads though because `list` will be populated which you'll most likely want to account for to prevent unnecessary requests.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to understand setState is not synchronized that means when you call setList(newDataList) that not gonna triggered refer [why setState is async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087156/9133304)
therefore you can use @spender solution
or useStateCallback hook but it's important understand **setState is not sync**

```
   const [state, setState] = useStateCallback([]);
   const addToList = (name) => {
   ........... your code
   setList(newDataList, () => {
      // call handleList function here
         handleList();
    }); 
    }
```