# Why is this.state not updated real-time after setState is issued?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to simulate the state by clicking a button. The 'before' status seems to have the correct value, but why is the 'after' not displaying the correct value even if the setState is already hit by the code?

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
    
        this.state = {isLoggedIn: false}
        this.OnClick = this.OnClick.bind(this);
    }

OnClick(){
        
        this.setState(prev =>
            {
                return (prev.isLoggedIn = !this.state.isLoggedIn);
            })

        console.log(`After setState value: ${this.state.isLoggedInstrong text}`) // setState is done, why is this.state displaying incorrect value?
    }

render()
    {
        console.log(`Before setState value: ${this.state.isLoggedIn}`)
        return <Login isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} OnClick={this.OnClick}  />
    }
}

import React from "react";

class Login extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        const {isLoggedIn, OnClick} = this.props;

        return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={OnClick} >{isLoggedIn ? "Log Out" : "Log In"} </button>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

OUTPUT:

"Before setState value: **false**"
(Initial display, button value is: **Log In**)

*When button is clicked:*
"After setState value: **false**"   <------ ***why false*** when setState has been hit already? Not real-time update until Render is called?

"Before setState value: **true**"
(Button value is now: **Log Out**)

Comment: because it is **not** a **synchronous** operation

Comment: To trigger the rerender the new state must be a *new* object. currently you update property of an object, but its still same object, so react framework dont know that its need to be rerendred

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)

Comment: Thanks guys, lots of learning I'm getting here, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I see in your code is you’re trying to mutate the state.

```js
this.setState(prev => {
  return (prev.isLoggedIn = !this.state.isLoggedIn);
})
```

You have to merge to the state not mutate it. You can do it simply by returning an object like this.

```
this.setState((prev) => {
   return { isLoggedIn: !prev.isLoggedIn };
});
```

This will fix all the weird behaviours in your code.

### Full Code

**App.js**

```js
import { Component } from "react";
import Login from "./Login";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { isLoggedIn: false };
    this.OnClick = this.OnClick.bind(this);
  }

  OnClick() {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      return { isLoggedIn: !prev.isLoggedIn };
    });

    console.log(`After setState value: ${this.state.isLoggedIn}`);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`Before setState value: ${this.state.isLoggedIn}`);
    return <Login isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} OnClick={this.OnClick} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Login.js**

```js
import { Component } from "react";

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn, OnClick } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={OnClick}>{isLoggedIn ? "Log Out" : "Log In"} </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/setstate-is-not-update-the-state-69141369-efw46

Comment: your codesandbox result seems right, but my console is not the same. It only becomes right when I put the "after" state inside a setTimeout() for 3 seconds which shows the asynchronous behavior suggested earlier. My console result is:  Before setState value: false
After setState value: false
Before setState value: true
After setState value: true
Before setState value: false
After setState value: false
Before setState value: true

Comment: @Datadump can you share a codesandbox here

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
this.setState({
   isLoggedIn:!this.state.isLoggedIn
})
```

or

```
this.setState(prev => ({
   isLoggedIn:!prev.isLoggedIn
}))
```