# How to get state of children from parent in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display the state of child component in parent component, but somehow the text "abcde" still not show, here is the sample code

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-ui-lib';

class ChidComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: '',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({text: 'abcde'});
            this.props.getText(this.state.text);
          }}>
          <Text>Get Text</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 40,
  },
});
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: '',
    };
  }
  getTextFromChild(value) {
    this.setState({text: value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
        <ChidComponent
          getText={this.getTextFromChild.bind(this)}
          press={() => this.setState({show: !this.state.show})}
          textStyle={style.text}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
export default ParentComponent;
```

But somehow the screen still empty, the 'abcde' still **until i click twice**, come from functional component so i don't know what going on, please help, thank you a lots

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (Yes, the question is about React Native, but the vast majority of React Native questions are really React questions, you can mock it up in React.)

Comment: It can run @T.J.Crowder, just because it a react-native so i cant run it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getTextFromChild` method in the `ParentComponent` is removing the `show` property from the state, update it to this:

```
 getTextFromChild(value) {
    this.setState({text: value, show: true });
  }
```

EDIT: `setState` is async, you can pass a callback function as an argument to access the updated state.

```
   <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({text: 'abcde'}, () => {
              this.props.getText(this.state.text);
           }); 
   }}>
```

Should work.

Comment: Thank for your answer, it can run, but i have to press twice, i still dont get it

Comment: I update the question

Comment: I still don't get it, as i know,  async function mean the `function will not run in order` but `run the same time`, so why when i press the setState wont run?  but thank you so much, the function run now

Comment: Glad it helped! Consider upvoting and accepting this answer. Regarding `setState` being async, you can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087156/3565182