# How to save and display data retrieved from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I've retrieved data in `JSON` format using `GET` request then I'm facing a problem in saving into my `state` so that I can display them into my `span`/`div`/`h1` using `map function`. Here's how my `JSON` data looks like:

```js
[
   {
        "projectName": "SHIBA INU",
        "projectToken": "SHIB",
        "tokenPrice": 0.2,
        "saleStart":{
            "$date": "2021-12-20T20:00:00.00Z"
        },
   {
        "projectName": "BITCOIN",
        "projectToken": "BTC",
        "tokenPrice": 200,
        "saleStart":{
            "$date": "2021-12-20T20:00:00.00Z"
   }
]
```

So I'm trying to do this way but I dont think it will work:

```js
const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState({})
useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(`my api`).then(res => {
        for(let i=0; i<res.data.length; i+1){
          setProjectData(...projectData, res.data[i])
        }
      }).catch(e => console.log("error: ", e));
    },[]);
```

I'm not sure whether I should save them into an array or an object

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket `]`in your data-example (fixed that for you). If you want to use an object like `{data:[...]}` or an array  like `[...]` is your choice, but looking at your example I guess your are looking for an array of objects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @iLuvLogix [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70337915/how-to-save-and-display-data-retrieved-from-database/70338055#comment124336688_70337915): from the info in your example, it seems like you're trying to store an array of objects, so you'll want to initialize your state with an array, and then add the items from the response to the array as well. You also don't need the loop: you can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) all of the array items into a new array along with the existing state in one step:

```js
const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`my api`).then(res => {
    setProjectData([...projectData, ...res.data]);
  }).catch(e => console.log("error: ", e));
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not updating your `i` value in your for loop. Since your `i` value never will be less than res.data.length, it will loop infinitely.
Instead you should use `i++` to increment it at each iteration:

```js
for(let i=0; i<res.data.length; i++)
```

Other than that setting your state like that is problematic. `setState` in React is async which means when you use it and access your `projectData` it won't promise you that you are getting the updated state right away. Instead you should try to update your state at once in your case.
Also check [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)