# How to change pagination variables in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am working on building pagination. I'm still working on my API to fetch posts based on pagination, but at the moment I am stuck on a problem with states.

In my main file (where the posts will be), my code looks like this:

```
// Import modules
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import url from "url";

// Import components
import { Snippet } from "../Snippet";
import { CreatePost } from "./CreatePost";
import { Pagination } from "./Pagination";

// Import styles
import "./css/Content.css";

// Axios Init
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:5000/api/`,
});

export class Content extends React.Component {
    state = {
        collections: [
            { title: "ReactJS", color: "red" },
            { title: "HTML", color: "cyan" },
            { title: "CSS", color: "pink" },
        ],
        snippets: [],
        limitSnippets: 3,
        page: 0,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getSnippets();
    }

    getSnippets = async () => {
        try {
            let data = await api
                .get(
                    `/snippets/fetchAll?limitSnippets=${this.state.limitSnippets}&page=${this.state.page}`,
                    {
                        body: {
                            limitSnippets: 3,
                            page: 1,
                        },
                    }
                )
                .then(({ data }) => data);
            this.setState({ snippets: data });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    updatePagination = (page) => {
        this.state.page = page;
        console.log(this.state.page);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="content-header">Snippets</h1>
                <CreatePost contentUpdater={this.getSnippets} />
                <Pagination updatePagination={this.updatePagination} />
                <div className="w-layout-grid grid">
                    {this.state.snippets.map((snippet, i) => {
                        return (
                            <Snippet
                                key={i}
                                title={snippet.title}
                                code={snippet.code}
                                updatedDate={snippet.updatedDate}
                                createdDate={snippet.createdDate}
                                language={snippet.language}
                                creator={snippet.creator}
                                collections={snippet.collections}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
                <Pagination />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Content;
```

In pagination file, my code looks like this:

```
export const Pagination = (props) => {
    // States
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    // Axios Init
    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: `http://localhost:5000/api/`,
    });

    const handleLeft = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (page > 0) {
            setPage(page - 1);
            props.updatePagination(page);
        } else {
            console.log("handleLeft(): page not > 0");
        }
        //props.updatePagination(page);
        //}
    };

    const handleRight = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // page < fetchAllPages
        setPage(page + 1);
        props.updatePagination(page);
    };

    /*useEffect(() => {
        props.updatePagination(page);
    }, [page]);
*/
    return (
        <div className="paginate-div">
            <div className="paginate-next">
                <div className="paginate-next-icon" onClick={handleLeft}>
                    <i className="fas fa-caret-left"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" className="paginate-button first w-inline-block">
                <div className="paginate-text">1</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="paginate-button w-inline-block">
                <div className="paginate-text">2</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="paginate-button w-inline-block">
                <div className="paginate-text">3</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="paginate-button w-inline-block">
                <div className="paginate-text">4</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="paginate-button w-inline-block">
                <div className="paginate-text">5</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="paginate-button w-inline-block">
                <div className="paginate-text">6</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="paginate-button last w-inline-block">
                <div className="paginate-text">...</div>
            </a>
            <div className="paginate-next" onClick={handleRight}>
                <div className="paginate-next-icon">
                    <i className="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I have my pagination component which is passed a prop that's a function to updatePagination(). The pagination component has functions for left and right button for switching thru pagination, and when it is clicked, the main file gets the pagination updated.

**The problem I am having (sorry if it is confusing by the way i worded this)**
The default page is 0 (which is basically page 1).
The **crazy** thing is when I press right (handleRight is called on submit), it stays at page 0, then if I click it again it goes to 1, then after if I press the left button (which called handleLeft on submit) while it is on page 1, it goes up to 2 somehow, but if I click it again it goes back down to 1, then if I click again it goes to 0.

Why is this strange problem occurring?

Answer (score 0):

`setPage` is asynchronous, so when you `setPage` to decrement and then immediately call `props.updatePage`, `props.updatePage` is receiving the old value of `page`. You can read all about this common problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync).

```
const handleRight = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Hey React, set page to page + 1 and rerender the component
        setPage(page + 1);
        // But before you do that, call props.updatePagination on the old value
        props.updatePagination(page);
    };
```

You should ask yourself, though, why you even store two stateful values of `page` at all (one in the parent component, one in the child component). Couldn't the `Content` component keep track of your page state (as it already does) and pass it down as a prop, getting rid of your need for a page state in the child component? This is called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), and it's a fundamental concept in React, which incentivizes you to use the least amount of state possible to avoid exactly this kind of desync. Furthermore, from the code you've shared, the `Pagination` component just displays the page numbers - why does it even need to be stateful at all?

Comment: that's a very very good point. im new to react so im still learning all these concepts... but anyways, before i convert the page state into a single component, can you tell me how to make sure page isnt the old value before calling updatePagination() ? just want to learn how i could do that, even though im going to change the code to fit your idea

Comment: I learned how to use useEffect() and with that, it worked!! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the old value of page was being used in updatePagination(), I fixed this by not running updatePagination(page) in the same place, I used useEffect(), and checked for changes to {page}, and ran updatePagination in there.

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.updatePagination(page);
}, [page]);
```

The handleLeft, handleRight functions were changed to look like this:

```
const handleLeft = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let newPage = page - 1;
        if (page > 0) {
            setPage(newPage);
        } else {
            console.log("handleLeft(): page not > 0");
        }

        //}
    };
```

**NOTE"**
In the comments section, someone made a point that I should not be storing the page number in two places, but rather store them in one place and pass it over as props. **I have not currently tried to do this**, but I plan on doing this soon. But for now, this is the best answer for this scenario.