# State depending on other state not updating when child changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to collect data to insert in database. I am using hooks states for this matter.

I have a products state:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState(
      image: '',
      tags: [],
      available_colors: colors,
      available_sizes: talles,
   })
```

the `available_colors` depends on other state which is an array of colors. This array can be pushed with new elements and they are printed in the html.
But the problem is, it is not updating in the `products` state.

Here is the colors state

```
   const [colors, setColors] = useState([
      { name: 'blue' },
      { name: 'green' },
      { name: 'red' },
   ])
```

I am updating it like this:

```
const setColorsAttr = async () => {
      const value = await Swal.fire({
         title: 'Nuevo Color',
         html: `
         <input type="text" id="talle-input" class="swal2-input"/>
      `,
         showCancelButton: true,
         focusConfirm: false,
         preConfirm: () => {
            const color = Swal.getPopup().querySelector("#talle-input").value
            return color
         }
      })

      if (value.isDismissed !== true) {
         setColors([
            ...colors,
            { name: value.value }
         ])
         setProduct({
           ...product,
           [product.available_colors]: colors
         })
      }
     
   }
```

But in the products isn't changing. I would appreciate your help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setColorsAttr` forms a closure over the current `colors` and `setColors` will update `colors` in the next render, so you can't use the latest `colors` right away.

You can use `useEffect` with colors as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setProduct(previousProduct => ({...previousProduct, available_colors: colors}))
}, [colors])
```

`setProduct` in `setColorsAttr` can be removed

Answer (score 1):

This happens because, setState works asynchronously, which means state doesn't update immediately.

To overcome this you need to update the product state in useEffect when color is updated.

```
useEffect(() => {   setProduct(previousProduct =>
({...previousProduct, available_colors: colors})) }, [colors])
```

To learn more about setState asynchronous working , checkout this . [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)