# React - console logs empty an array and then logs a populated array after a second button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am running into a slight problem with using React and its hooks. I am trying to print out an array from an API, but it first prints as an empty array to the console, and then only when I click the button again does it prints the array.

Here is the function I'm using to make the array from API data:

```
 const getChampion = () => {
        for(let i = 0; i < getData.length; i++){
            let individualChamp = champPeep.current.value;
            if(getData[i].Name === individualChamp){
                // console.log(getData[i]);

                setShowChampion(individualChamp);
                setChampionTitle(getData[i].Title);

                let hitPoints = getData[i].Hp
                let attack = getData[i].Attack;
                let defense = getData[i].Defense;
                let attackRange = getData[i].AttackRange;
                let armor = getData[i].Armor;

                setRadarData([hitPoints, attack, defense, attackRange, armor]);
                console.log(radarData) //returns empty array don't know why
            }

        } //! Have to click search twice to update array to new array

    } //Get Champion name and check to see if it is found in the API
```

Here is the button the input field that I assigned to this function:

```
return(
 <div>
                    <div className='search'>
                        <input ref={champPeep} type="search" id='champion-search' placeholder='e.g Annie' />
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={getChampion} className='btn-prim'>Search</button>
                </div>
)
```

And this is what is being logged to the console when I click on button `btn-prim`:

```
[]
```

And when I click the `btn-prim` button again this is then logged (which is correct):

```
(5) [524, 2, 3, 625, 19]
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous in react, so when you try to log `radarData` immediately after `setRadarData` it displays previous data stored in `radarData`. You can use useEffect hook to log current `radarData` state

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(radarData)
}, [radarData])
```

why React setStates are async : [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that instead of you using

`console.log(radarData) //returns empty array don't know why`

try to add the `useEffect` hook to log the value of `radarData` whenever it changed.

Use something like:

```
useEffect(() => {console.log(radarData)}, [radarData])
```

Answer (score 1):

State updates will reflect in their next rerender and not immediately. This has already been solved.

Basically your

```
setRadarData([hitPoints, attack, defense, attackRange, armor]);
console.log(radarData) //returns empty array because its still using the default state {}.
```

Refer to *[The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)*.