# State not being updated with React's state hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am posting an image to my Cloudinary account and want to save the URL from the response in the `imageUrl` state. When console logging the response URL, it shows me the Cloudinary URL correctly but the `setImageUrl` doesn't seem to be working.

*I have changed my Cloudinary details to 'dummy' for security reasons*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./image.css";

function Image() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");
  const postDetails = async () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", image);
    data.append("upload_preset", "dummy");
    data.append("cloud_name", "dummy");
    const settings = { method: "POST", body: data };
    try {
      const fetchData = await fetch(
        "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dummy/image/upload",
        settings
      );
      const resData = await fetchData.json();
      console.log(resData.url);
      if (resData) {
        setImageUrl(resData.url);
        console.log("imageUrl", imageUrl);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="file-field input-field">
        <div className="btn #64b5f6 blue darken-1">
          <span>Uplaod Image</span>
          <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])} />
        </div>
        <div className="file-path-wrapper">
          <input className="file-path validate" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        className="btn waves-effect waves-light #64b5f6 blue darken-1"
        onClick={() => postDetails()}
      >
        Submit post
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Image;
```

Comment: In react the setState is an asynchrone function. That is why you cannot see the result immediately after using setState See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync

Comment: I see, yeah I have added a <p>{imageUrl}</p> and can see it is setting, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see that in general there is nothing wrong with the logic.
Check if `if (resData)` is really a `true` value.
You can do it like that to be more sure about the value `!! resdata` or`Boolean (resData)`, but keep in mind that an empty object or an empty array will be a truthy value.

If there is no error in `try catch` statement, and restData is a truthy value there is no chance that`setImageUrl ()`will not be working.

Comment: SOLVED, it was working, but I wasn't seeing it in the log due to the asynchronous nature of setState. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**State update happens asynchronously**, so when you call the `setImageUrl` state updater function, the state doesn't get updated immediately, first the entire `postDetails` function runs and then a re-render would take place (meaning your functional component gets called again) and this time the `useState` hook will return the updated value for the `imageUrl` state.

So your logic is correct, in the next render you would get the updated value which you can use in your JSX, but your expectation that the log would print the updated state immediately after the state updater is called is wrong.

Also, on a side note, you don't need to create a new function to pass it to `onClick` like this: `onClick={() => postDetails()}`, you can simply pass the `postDetails` function like this: `onClick={postDetails}` because you don't want to pass any arguments to the function, so creating a new function is unnecessary.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams Please take a look if this answers your question. You can accept this answer to close this thread!