# Why does setting state in componentDidMount require setTimeout to work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that looks something like the below (yes, I know React hooks exist...). I've created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-frog-4o4s9y?file=/src/App.js) example too.

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loadingStatus: "idle"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    debugger;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loadingStatus: "loading" });
    }, 1);

    setInterval(() => {
      const loadingStatus =
        this.state.loadingStatus === "loading" ? "complete" : "loading";
      this.setState({ loadingStatus });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    const { loadingStatus } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>loadingStatus: {this.state.loadingStatus}</div>
        <div role="status">
          {loadingStatus === "loading" && (
            <img
              alt="loading"
              src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif?20151024034921"
            />
          )}
          {loadingStatus === "complete" && (
            <span className="visually-hidden">Loading has completed</span>
          )}
        </div>
        {loadingStatus === "complete" && (
          <div>Content has loaded. The page will reload again momentarily.</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This component demonstrates how to make a page loading indicator that is accessible to screen reader users. The key is the use of an element with `role="status"` which will announce when its content changes. It needs to contain:

- nothing initially so that, when it does have content, the new content will be announced.
- the loading indicator when the component is in a loading state which should occur immediately after the component mounts.
- a visually hidden element after loading is complete which will announce to screen reader users that loading is complete.

The issue I'm having is that when I change the loading status from "idle" to "loading" in componentDidMount, it doesn't "register" in the DOM unless I wrap it in a setTimeout(), even just a 1 ms delay.  If I don't have the setTimeout(), the content change in my `role="status"` element is not announced.

What's interesting is that, if you remove the setTimeout() and open up dev tools in the browser, the `debugger;` breaks and you can see that the UI *is* rendered when the status is "idle". This has me confused why there is a need for a delay.

**To be clear, the problem is that, without the setTimeout(), the initial announcing of "loading" does not occur. You'll need a screen reader (eg. NVDA) to test.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hahahah... In codeSanBox it is working fine

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans Updated the post with the note in bold to clarify what that issue is.

Answer (score 2):

The `componentDidMount` method is called **after** the component has been rendered. This is why you can see it when you add the debugger statement.

Calling `setState` inside `componentDidMount` will then actually trigger a second call to `render`. Which reads the new state and updates the DOM.

I'm not sure why you were using `setInterval` but if you simplify your example it actually works the way you would expect.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ loadingStatus: 'loading' });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ loadingStatus: 'complete' });
  }, 3000);
}
```

Which causes the following flow:

- state = { loadingStatus: 'idle' }
- render
- componentDidMount
- setState({ loadingStatus: 'loading' })
- render
- 3 seconds later... setState({ loadingStatus: 'complete' })
- render

In the example above `setTimeout(..., 3000)` represents a simulated API call. You would most likely want to do an asynchronous operation instead like this :

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ loadingStatus: 'loading' });

  fetch('/your/api/endpoint').then(response => {
    // do something with the response
    this.setState({ loadingStatus: 'complete' });
  });
}
```

If you're still having trouble with it after trying the above method, it might be because [setState is async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087156) and the changes you make can be batched if they happen in one continuous execution flow. Wrapping your code in a `requestAnimationFrame` callback will ensure that the previous render is complete before updating the status.

```
componentDidMount() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    this.setState({ loadingStatus: 'loading' });

    fetch('/your/api/endpoint').then(response => {
      // do something with the response
      this.setState({ loadingStatus: 'complete' });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I won't be able to check it before the bounty expires so I'll just give it to you now. May ping you when I have time to test it.

Comment: Thanks! That's very courteous of you. I'm on here every day so just let me know how it goes when you get the chance.