# Why setState return empty in react on its first time. Whenever changes made it showing the result

Tags: reactjs, async-await, promise, use-effect

I am new to react.I have trying to set the value using useState. But on first time it is not showing. But on next loading it shows the value.

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    
    
    const Home = () => {
      
      const [trendingFood, setTrendingFood] = useState([]);
      
      useEffect(() => {
        fectedData();
      }, [])
    
      const fectedData = async() => {
        const foodData =await fetch(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_TEMP_KEY}&number=10`);
        const resp =await foodData.json();
        setTrendingFood(resp);
        console.log(resp)
        console.log(trendingFood);
      }
    
    
      return <div>Home</div>
    };
    
    export default Home;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)

Answer (score 1):

The `setState` call is asynchronous and will take time to update. To see the updated value you need to move the second `console.log` to the component level. When each time it rerenders(i.e when the state changes) you can see the value:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [trendingFood, setTrendingFood] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fectedData();
  }, []);

  const fectedData = async () => {
    const foodData = await fetch(
      `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_TEMP_KEY}&number=10`
    );
    const resp = await foodData.json();
    setTrendingFood(resp);
    console.log("a: ", resp);
  };

  console.log("b: ", trendingFood);

  return <div>Home</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Demo:

[image: Edit tender-brook-os4rci]

Comment: I want to list the array of value in return like. {trending.map((value)=><p>value</p>)}. But due to no value intially it is breaking. how could solve the problem Amila

Comment: use optional chaining operator(`?.`) -> `{trending?.map((value)=><p>value</p>)}`