# Find Average of Firebase Firestore Array in JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a simple app where I could record shrinkage of material. The input parameters are the first and second material thickness. Below is my fetch data where I query through the values I would like to display and this works fine for displaying those filtered items.

I try and only set my delta values inside my collection
I console.log the array to see what is inside and also try to find the sum of this array.

```
const [firstPara, setFirstPara] = useState("");
const [secondPara, setSecondPara] = useState("");
const [deltaList, setDeltaList] = useState([0]);
const [theAmountData, setTheAmountData] = useState(null);

const fetchData = async () => {
   const weldShrinkageQuery = query(collection(db, "WeldShrinkageRecord"), 
   where("firstMaterialThickness", "==", firstPara), 
   where("secondMaterialThickness", "==", secondPara),
   );
   const theData2 = await getDocs(weldShrinkageQuery);
        
   setTheAmountData(theData2.docs.length)
   setDeltaData(theData2.delta)

   // filter only delta values inside of query
   const filteredDeltaValues = theData2.docs.map((doc) => ({
      delta: doc.delta,
   }))
   setDeltaList(filteredDeltaValues);


   console.log("this is the array: " + deltaList)

   // try to find addition of array
   let addition = deltaList.reduce((value, sums = 0) =>
   sums = sums + value.delta);

   console.log(addition)
   };
```

this is how my values are stored in firestore:

[image]

when running the script I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkoCW.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show: 1) How the two snippets are related. In fact, it's typically best to ensure all the necessary code is in a single snippet that we can copy/paste to run and  reproduce the problem. 2) How `deltaList` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you declare `deltaList` as:

```
const [deltaList, setDeltaList] = useState();
```

This means that `deltaList` doesn't have an initial value. If you then calculate the average of it before it gets a value, you'll get the error you posted.

The simplest fix is to initialize `deltaList` as an empty array with:

```
const [deltaList, setDeltaList] = useState([]);
                                       //
```

---

From reading the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Reduce_of_empty_array_with_no_initial_value) for the error, it seems that `reduce` in this overload uses a value from the array as its initial value - so you can't pass an empty array.

So you can pass an array with `0` as its only value:

```
const [deltaList, setDeltaList] = useState([0]);
                                        //
```

Comment: Hello Frank, thanks for your reply!. Sorry, I forgot to add this part. I have edited my question. I still get the same error.

Comment: Frank thanks again for your reply, I tried this and my output is 0. The state isn't setting

Comment: So the error you posted is gone? Does it make sense, based on what I explained, why you were getting the error - and why the change removes that error? --- After that you'll want to set a breakpoint on `setDeltaList(filteredDeltaValues);`, run in a debugger, and see what value you are setting.

Comment: I think I get it, by `setDeltaList(filteredDeltaValues)` I am setting all values inside my collection. If I would only like to set my delta values that are inside of deltaList, how would I be able to do so?

Comment: Is your latest edit really how the two code blocks are in your app? That will never work, because [setting state is an asynchronous operation in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync).

Comment: yes, the latest edit is how I have my app currently. I am very new at js / react, any suggestions on what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the link I shared in my previous comment? That explains the second problem you have. --- Third problem is then how to read a specific field from each document in your query results. --- I recommend simplifying the problem, as we're three problems deep into a use-case. E.g. ignoring ReactJS and any web framwork, just in plain JavaScript: can you read a bunch of documents and then get a field from each document in the resuliting `QuetySnapshot`? If that works, adding ReactJS to it becomes just one more step, rather than one of a string of problems.