# How to have proper bidirectional binding on ClojureScript with Reagent?

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent, react-toolbox

I'm writing a wrapper for [React Toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com) for ClojureScript/Reagent called [Reagent Toolbox](https://github.com/dashmantech/reagent-toolbox). In React Toolbox, there's [an input component](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/input) that's used like this:

```
<Input type='text' 
       label='Name' 
       name='name' value={this.state.name}
       onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}
       maxLength={16 } />
```

I created a Reagent component around that React component like this:

```
(def input (reagent/adapt-react-class (.-Input js/ReactToolbox)))
```

so that I can use it like this:

```
[reagent-toolbox.core/input {:label      "Name"
                             :name       "name"
                             :type       "text"
                             :value      @name
                             :max-length 16
                             :on-change  (fn [value event] (reset! name value))}]
```

But unlike the React version, in the Reagent version, each key press on the input causes the component to be re-rendered making the cursor jump to the end. You can experience that effect here: http://reagent-toolbox-docs.dashman.tech/input

Whan am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error in the past, but it took me a while to remember why this occurs.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28922465/781707) explains the underlying problem.  This occurs in Reagent, because *all* Reagent re-renders are async.  Therefore, every controlled input explicitly sets the `.valid` attribute on the DOM (which, depending on the browser, places the cursor at the end).

[This Reagent issue](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/pull/126) goes into the most detail about this problem and finally merges a solution for Reagent's inputs.

The short answer seems to be that simply using `reagent/adapt-react-class` here doesn't seem to be enough.  It looks like you will have to wrap the adapted class and apply the same fix by inspecting `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` and repositioning the cursor.