# React.js input cursor reset with async onChange handler

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, input, cursor, reset

If I have the following react component:

```
class Cmpt extends Component {
   setValue( e ) {
     this.setState({ value : e.target.value });
   }
   render() {
     return <input value={this.state.val} onChange={this.setValue.bind(this)}/>
   }
}
```

Now this works as expected, editing the text doesn't reset the cursor to the end of the input. If I modify it such that the setState happens in async, the cursor reset occurs:

```
class Cmpt extends Component {
   setValue( e ) {
     setTimeout( () =>
       this.setState({ value : e.target.value }) );
   }
   render() {
     return <input value={this.state.val} onChange={this.setValue.bind(this)}/>
   }
}
```

Obviously the fix is to not call `setState` synchronously - but I don't understand why the async version doesn't work properly. In my head, the chain of events is as follows:

1. User adds a character to an input field, changing it from ACD to A**B**CD
2. The value of the input DOM node is changed to ABCD to reflect this
3. Some time passes
4. `setState` is called - changing the state of the react component from ACD to ABCD
5. a `render` call is triggered - the React diffing algorithm compares the DOM nodes value (ABCD) to the value of `this.state.value` (ABCD). It sees that both are the same and therefore doesn't trigger a redraw and the cursor is preserved

Clearly my mental model is wrong because a redraw is being triggered - causing the cursor reset.

Please can anyone explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In ReactJS, why does \`setState\` behave differently when called synchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922275/in-reactjs-why-does-setstate-behave-differently-when-called-synchronously)

Answer (score 0):

A state changes will always trigger a new `render` call. After that React itself decides on what to re-render. But it will always get triggered by changing the state. Even if you do

```
this.setState({})
```

it will call the `render` method.

Comment: for sure, but my question was why React was choosing to re-render the text input (causing the cursor reset) when setState was called async vs sync

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, found a duplicate question that answers my question:

[In ReactJS, why does `setState` behave differently when called synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922275/in-reactjs-why-does-setstate-behave-differently-when-called-synchronously)

I can't figure out how to mark my own question as a duplicate unfortunately :(

My mental model of the order of events is wrong. Apparently react triggers a synchronous re-render at the end of every event handler, so render is getting called **after** the DOM changes, but **before** the react state has changed - causing a redraw and a cursor reset

Thanks all

T