# I would like to understand this weird behavior of setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

So I've been working with react for a while now, and I've noticed this weird behavior when I use the method **setState** provided by the useState hook, when I update the value of a piece of state using setState and I reference that state immediately after updating it, it give me the previous value of the state before updating but it shows correctly when I display the state in the DOM.

```
<TextField
    label="Username"
    value={handle}
    error={error.hasError}
    id="username"
    onChange={e => {
        setHandle(e.target.value);
        console.log("Ran");
        for (let i = 0; i < e.target.value.length; i++) {
            if (!isAllowedChar(handle[i]))
                return setError({
                    message: "Username should only contain alphabets, digits, _ and .",
                    hasError: true,
                });
            setError({ message: "", hasError: false });
        }
    }}
/>
```

when I begin typing in the input field, the onChange handler updates on each key stroke as expected and prints ran to the console, the value of the input field updates correctly on each keystroke as expected but the next bit of code where I reference the state **handle** after updating it with **setHandle** it gives me the previous state so my conditions are not satisfied until after another keystroke even if there is an error on the previous keystroke.

I would like to know if there's something I'm doing wrong or if it's just a weird bug in **useState**

Comment: It's not a bug. setState is asynchronous.

Comment: @Dilshan so i checked their documentation, the state is updated in batch asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State Updates May Be Asynchronous. It is mentioned clearly in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous
If you still question why setState is asynchronous, can check this thread: [In ReactJS, why does `setState` behave differently when called synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922275/in-reactjs-why-does-setstate-behave-differently-when-called-synchronously)

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not working as expected because it's not updating the state fast enough, you can 'wait' for it to update with useEffect hooks.